# apply template binding with ko.applyBindingsToNode

Tags: knockout.js, carousel, owl-carousel

I've created a custom binding to integration owlcarousel. The carousel needs to be bound after the template rendering is complete. I'm trying to use ko.applyBindingsToNode to render template binding and apply carousel on it but it isn't working. The programs array passed to foreach in template is an observableArray. It grows after the template binding is applied.

The binding is applied on UL list with attributes:

```
class="owl-carousel" data-bind="owlcarouselTemplate: { templateOptions: { name: 'grid-row-template', list: programs }, carouselOptions: { items : 5 } }"
```

The custom binding is as follows:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.owlcarouselTemplate = {
init : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
/**/
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var tmplBinding = value.templateOptions;

    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { template: { name: tmplBinding.name, foreach: tmplBinding.list } }, bindingContext);


    /**/
},
update : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var tmplBinding = value.templateOptions;
    var owl = $(element).data('owlCarousel');

    valueAccessor = function() {
        return { name: tmplBinding.name, foreach: tmplBinding.list };
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

    if( owl ) {
        owl.destroy();
        owl.reinit();
    }
    else
        $(element).owlCarousel(value.carouselOptions);
}
```

}